# Why does python expects a statement when I use "except FileNotFoundError" function? Isn't the "FileNotFoundError" already a statement?

Tags: python

I'm making an app that locks your apps. The only way you can open them is if you plug in a flash drive that has the correct id. But, python expects a statement when I write, "except File Not Found Error"? Here's the code, I'm using hyperlink because stack overflow keeps giving me an error when I post the code here

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import subprocess
import random

# Variables
authorization = False

# Opening save file
with open("save.txt", "r") as fa:
    current_id = fa.read()

# Open a file
path = r"G:\Authorization\5.txt"

# Checking if it has the correct ID
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    file_contents = f.read()
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("ACCESS DENIED")
    if file_contents == str(current_id):
        authorization = True
```

Comment: It seems that you are missing the "try" statement in the "try/except".

Answer (score 2):

```
# Checking if it has the correct ID
try:
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        file_contents = f.read()
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("ACCESS DENIED")
    if file_contents == str(current_id):
        authorization = True
```

Except only work with a "try" statement aswell. This shouldn't give you a missing statement. [Try/except documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/tutorial/errors.html)

Comment: Note that your link is for the (now unsupported) Python 3.5, and in French. You can use [try/except documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/tutorial/errors.html) for the Python 3.10 documentation in English.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I hide the errors? So it only shows ACCESS DENIED?

Comment: nevermind, I got it working after putting the "except filenotfounderror" function after the if statement